# Hide value from showing behind loading spinner on Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an aura component with a loading spinner that spins while the page is render. When it's rendering, it will show the section headings on the page meanwhile. in my code below i want to hide "Opportunity value:" from showing on the faded screen that shows when the loading spinner is spinning especially in situations where it doesn't mean the IF condition.

My cmp file

```
 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.opptyValue != 0}">
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <b>Opportunity value: </b> {!v.opptyValue}%
                            </span>                             
                        </div> 
                        <aura:set attribute="else">
                            <span>
                             0%
                            </span>
                        </aura:set>
                    </aura:if>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You just need another `aura:if` to hide the component when it shouldn't be shown.

Comment: that worked- thank you!!